# How to dock the Output dialog in Visual Studio without covering Solution Explorer?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2022. I wanted to resize the Output dialog to make it a bit shorter, but I accidentally misclicked and I ended up making the Output dialog windowed.

So, then I dragged the Output dialog back to Visual Studio 2022, and while it did place the Output dialog back into the window, the Output dialog now covers other dialogs, for example Solution Explorer.

Please take a look at the image below - the Output dialog covers the Solution Explorer; *I don't want it to cover the Solution Explorer, I just want it to be like it was initially (e.g. **default layout**) - it was docked, but didn't cover over dialogs*:
[image]

Is there a way to return the Output dialog layout back to what it was initially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually receive any answer within nearly 20 hours, and the only solution I found was to reset the window layout.

`Window` -> `Reset Window Layout` -> `Yes`.

[image]

[image]

You'll notice that things like Solution Explorer or Toolbox will reset their width to their defaults. Floating (windowed) dialogs will also disappear. But more importantly, the Output dialog will now look like the default:

[image]

I'd recommend selecting `Window` -> `Save Window Layout` first and then giving the window layout name, so that the window layout is saved in case to revert the window layout again. To revert it, select `Window` - > `Apply Window Layout`, and click on the name of the window layout saved.

If someone posts an answer that provides a solution to this problem without resetting window layout or other settings, I will definitely mark it as accepted.